# Tensorflow: why is the outcome of single neural network node without activation function different then my own calculation?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

i created a single node with 3 inputs and one output with bias 0 and no activation function.
as far as i understand, the only thing that happens here is a matrix multiplication between the input vector and the randomly initialized weights but when i do the multiplication myself with the same inputs and weights i get a different outcome? what am i missing/doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

i base my calculation on some code provided [here](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/python-tensorflow-tutorial/)

here is the code:

```
def example_code(self):
    import tensorflow as tf

    data = [[1.0,2.0,3.0]]
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[1,3],name="mydata")
    node = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
    y = node(x)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    print("input: "+str(data))
    outcome = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:data})
    #print("outcome from tensorflow: "+str(outcome))
    weights = node.get_weights()[0]
    bias = node.get_weights()[1]
    print("weights: "+str(weights))
    print("bias: "+str(bias))
    print("outcome from tensorflow: " + str(outcome))
    outcome = tf.matmul(data,weights)
    print("manually calculated outcome: "+str(sess.run(outcome)))
```

output from code:

```
input: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
weights: [[ 0.72705185] [-0.70188504] [ 0.5336163 ]]
bias: [0.]
outcome from tensorflow: [[-1.3463312]]
manually calculated outcome: [[0.9241307]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tf.layers` is not using uses is not using your session `sess`. This in turn results in different initializations for the weights, hence the two different values. `tf.layers` ends up using `tf.keras.backend.get_session()` to retrieve the session used for initialization and retrieval of weights (`node.get_weights()`). `tf.keras.backend.get_session()` tries to use the default session if there is one, and if there is not then it creates its own session. In this case, `sess` is not configured as default session (only `tf.InteractiveSession` gets automatically configured as default session on construction). The simplest fix is to use `tf.Session` in the recommended way, as a context manager:

```
def example_code(self):
    import tensorflow as tf
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        data = [[1.0,2.0,3.0]]
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[1,3],name="mydata")
        node = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
        y = node(x)
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        print("input: "+str(data))
        outcome = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:data})
        #print("outcome from tensorflow: "+str(outcome))
        weights = node.get_weights()[0]
        bias = node.get_weights()[1]
        print("weights: "+str(weights))
        print("bias: "+str(bias))
        print("outcome from tensorflow: " + str(outcome))
        outcome = tf.matmul(data,weights)
        print("manually calculated outcome: "+str(sess.run(outcome)))
```

This will set `sess` as default session, and also it will make sure its resources are freed when the function is finished (which was another issue in your code). If for whatever reason you want to use some session as default but do not want to close it with the context manager, you can just use `as_default()`:

```
def example_code(self):
    import tensorflow as tf
    sess = tf.Session():
    with sess.as_default():
        data = [[1.0,2.0,3.0]]
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[1,3],name="mydata")
        node = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
        y = node(x)
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        print("input: "+str(data))
        outcome = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:data})
        #print("outcome from tensorflow: "+str(outcome))
        weights = node.get_weights()[0]
        bias = node.get_weights()[1]
        print("weights: "+str(weights))
        print("bias: "+str(bias))
        print("outcome from tensorflow: " + str(outcome))
        outcome = tf.matmul(data,weights)
        print("manually calculated outcome: "+str(sess.run(outcome)))
    # You need to manually ensure that the session gets closed after
    sess.close()
```